# How to start singlestore docker container quickly?

Tags: docker, testcontainers, singlestore

Is there way to disable studio, toolbox, make less leaves?
I use singlestore for spring boot tests in [testcontainers-spring-boot](https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/testcontainers-spring-boot/tree/develop/embedded-memsql) and I want to container start quicker as studio and toolbox is not required for tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use https://github.com/singlestore-labs/singlestoredb-dev-image which doesn't include Toolbox. It should also be faster than singlestore/cluster-in-a-box.